# Can I safely use `self.request.user.is_authenticated` in views?

Tags: python, django

We are using Django 2.1 for [Speedy Net](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net). There is a view which I want to be different for admin (staff) than for regular users. I added the following (3 first) lines to the code:

```
def get_user_queryset(self):
    if (self.request.user.is_authenticated):
        if ((self.request.user.is_staff) and (self.request.user.is_superuser)):
            return User.objects.get_queryset()
    return User.objects.active()
```

But the problem is, one of the tests fails with an error message:

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
```

([link](https://travis-ci.org/speedy-net/speedy-net/builds/638756979)) And I want to know - Is it safe to use `self.request.user.is_authenticated` in views? Should I fix the test to work or can my code fail in production? The test uses `RequestFactory()`, is there a problem with `RequestFactory()` not containing attribute 'user'? Or is there a problem with my code which may also fail in production?

If I should fix the test, how do I do it? Here is the code of the test which fails:

```
class UserMixinTextCaseMixin(object):
    def set_up(self):
        super().set_up()
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = ActiveUserFactory(slug='look-at-me', username='lookatme')
        self.other_user = ActiveUserFactory()

    def test_find_user_by_exact_slug(self):
        view = UserMixinTestView.as_view()(self.factory.get('/look-at-me/some-page/'), slug='look-at-me')
        self.assertEqual(first=view.get_user().id, second=self.user.id)
```

By the way, I'm not sure what is the purpose of `slug='look-at-me'` in the `view = ...` line of the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54605974/1412564) on Stack Overflow.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory):

> ```
>     # Recall that middleware are not supported. You can simulate a
>     # logged-in user by setting request.user manually.
>     request.user = self.user
>
>     # Or you can simulate an anonymous user by setting request.user to
>     # an AnonymousUser instance.
>     request.user = AnonymousUser()
> ```

Adding `request.user = AnonymousUser()` in the tests solves the problem:

```
class UserMixinTextCaseMixin(object):
    def set_up(self):
        super().set_up()
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = ActiveUserFactory(slug='look-at-me', username='lookatme')
        self.other_user = ActiveUserFactory()

    def test_find_user_by_exact_slug(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/look-at-me/some-page/')
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
        view = UserMixinTestView.as_view()(request=request, slug='look-at-me')
        self.assertEqual(first=view.get_user().id, second=self.user.id)
```

Replacing `MIDDLEWARE` with `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` doesn't solve the problem and we are already using `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'`, but this is not used by `RequestFactory()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... It's safe to use **`request.user`** or **`self.request.user`** in Django and it is the **Django way** of checking whether the `User` is authenticated or not.

> `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'`

Django assigning the ***authenticated user*** to the **request** object within the [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) execution, specifically within the [**`AuthenticationMiddleware`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) class ([source-code of `AuthenticationMiddleware` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7d8df4ad032c6241776c2b3ec6c76af9dd84fda3/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L15)).

So, adding the `AuthenticationMiddleware` class to the `Middleware` settings or creating your own middleware class is will solve the `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'` error.

Comment: Django says "All middleware classes included with Django are compatible with both settings.". Why do we have to use the old-style `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` then?

Comment: We are using `MIDDLEWARE` and not `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: Did your middleware settings have ` 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` middleware class?

Comment: @Uri Anyway, I have updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for "Yeah... It's safe to use request.user or self.request.user in Django..." but your solution doesn't fix our problem. Please see my answer below.